# How to select the lowest level in a hierarchy of enum

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I have this enum:

```
public enum Enums{
    AAA1,
    BBB1,
    CCC1,
    DDD1
}
```

It is inside a class that is saving all the enums inside a list.
My question is, for example, if I have {AAA1, CCC1} inside the list, how can I check for all the enums and only get the lowest enum inside the list, {CCC1}?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Comparator` and and the `sort()` method of a `List` to first sort the list of enum values and then pick the first or last element depending on whether you want the *lowest* or *highest* enum value.

You can adjust the `Comparator` to whatever you need. Reasonable choices could be the `name` of the enum or the `ordinal`. Alternatively you could also overwrite `toString()` and use that to sort the Enums or you could even assign the enum and attribute `key` and sort it using that.

Here how you would sort the `List` using the the enum value name.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var list = new ArrayList<Enums>();
        list.add(Enums.CCC1);
        list.add(Enums.AAA1);

        System.out.println(list);
        // compare using ordinal
        // list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Enum::ordinal));
        // compare using the enum value name
        list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Enum::name));
        var lowest = list.get(0);
        var highest = list.get(list.size() - 1);
        System.out.println(list);

    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
[CCC1, AAA1]
[AAA1, CCC1]
```